# Apollo Client 3 evict query result - doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Using Apollo Client 3 and eed to remove all the results of a query regardless of the arguments. Tried like this;

```
       cache.evict({
          id: "ROOT_QUERY",
          fieldName: "countries"
        });

        cache.gc();
```

However nothing removed from cache, `__APOLLO_CLIENT__.cache.data` still has all the result in the cache.
I can remove a single **Country** object on the other hand.

You can see it here [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-client3-evict-query-result-qfrpr?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: reseting store is for that

Comment: Couldn't find any sample !...

Comment: I want to remove only a specific query's result, not to clear whole store.

Comment: ok, I explored this problem a bit ... cache entry is deleted (`console.log("cache", cache.data.data);`),  - `gc()` doesn't matter  ... but problem is with hooks, view isn't rerendered when 'data' is cleared ... IMHO it's an apollo issue as change is propagated ( `this.broadcastWatches();` called), 'data' should be set to undefined again  .... workaround? writeQuery with ampty data?

Comment: thanks @xadm. You're right, it's about `useLazyQuery` and `cache.evict({
          id: "ROOT_QUERY",
          fieldName: "countries"
        });`

After this cache.evict, apollo client somehow can not reconcile query and the cache, so it queries again. Do you think that we can use this same `useLazyQuery` hook in out page with different fetch policies to overcome this?

Comment: not refetched (check network tab), just not catched (by hook internal observable) cache entry change ... probably you can force omponent rerendering by refetch (from hook) called with cache-only policy

Answer (score 6):

Simple adding `broadcast: false` parameter solved the problem;

```
               cache.evict({
                  id: 'ROOT_QUERY',
                  fieldName: 'countries',
                  broadcast: false,
                });
                cache.gc();
```

Comment: broadcast : false did the trick, why is it not there in the docs or I am not able to find it  :/